# Rails Api test UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an API and, upon writing the tests, I run into a strange UrlGenerator Error.

I have an API on version one and this is my Users controller.

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here is the spec for that users controller

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) { request.headers['Accept'] = "application/vnd.marketplace.v1" }

  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryBot.create :user
      get :show, format: :json
    end

    it "returns the information about a reporter on a hash" do
      user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
      expect(user_response[:email]).to eql @user.email
    end

    it { should respond_with 200 }
  end
end
```

When I run this spec I get the following error message: `Failure/Error: get :show, format: :json

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/users", :format=>:json}`
```

I have only one route for my API:

```
api_user GET  /users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#show {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>:json}
```

Does anybody know why I would be getting this error? It seems to me that, based on the route returned from the api routes list, this should be working. My `routes.rb` file is listed below:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, :only => [:show]
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think the one route you have defined needs an :id, and the Error indicates its looking for a route without an :id specified. Perhaps what you need is something like `get :show, params: { id: @user.id }`

Comment: Ah, okay. So originally I just had `get :show, id: @user.id, format: :json` and was getting an error id and seem to have removed that entirely for some reason. Worked great. Thank you!

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer if you have a moment to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the show route that you have defined requires an `:id` parameter, but the call for `get :show` from the test does not send it.

From Rspec, you can send the id with something like:

`get :show, params: { id: @user.id }, format: :json`